# Where does Bootstrap inline form gap between label and input element come from?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed something that I could not understand.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-inline

Where is the this gap between the 'label' and the 'input' coming from?

Both of them are inline. Are they supposed to attach each other?

I actually copy the code into my project. They are attached to each other. But my project is messy. I want to understand why on the bootstrap website, they are not attached.

They are 'inline-block'. In their 'Computed' tab, the margin is '-'. So zero. Right?

Where is this margin coming from? 
[image]

Comment: You're using bootstrap 4 in your project, right?

Comment: No bootstrap 3. I think it seems to me that the 'inline-block' automatically inject a unseeable 'whitespace' charactor before and after itself right before render itself. This is just how I feel.

Comment: You're Right, I've tested it locally, this space is automatically generated from `inline-block` property,

Comment: thanks. that explains. my project is angular and it erased all whitespace after compile

Comment: i'll add it as answer to share the idea with everyone

Comment: you can read more about inline-block and how you can remove the space. https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is coming from `inline-block` property, it's adding some space between elements which is inlined by default,

See This Example with no libraries added

```css
 div { 
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    div:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color: lightblue
    }
    div:nth-child(even) { 
      background-color: lightcoral;
    }
```

```html
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From CSS-Tricks.com:

> This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements
>   on a line works. You want spaces between words that you type to be
>   spaces right? The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces
>   between words. That's not to say the spec couldn't be updated to say
>   that spaces between inline-block elements should be nothing, but I'm
>   fairly certain that is a huge can of worms that is unlikely to ever
>   happen.

[Read More](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)